# React mount one of same component (popover) at time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to have onboarding popover that show only on first login, but i want to show only one popover at time, if i close one popover, next one is showing, how can i do it ?

i am using `window.localStorage` to check if the popover have already been displayed

here is my component

```
type Props = {
  header?: string,
  content: string,
  color: string,
  name: string,
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const Popover = ({ header, content, color, children, name }: Props) => {
  const storage = window.localStorage
  const popovers = storage['popovers'] ? JSON.parse(storage['popovers']) : storage.setItem('popovers', JSON.stringify([]))
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(!popovers?.includes(name))
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: `(${theme.isMobile})` })

  console.log('storage > ', storage)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsVisible(false)
    !popovers.includes(name) && storage.setItem('popovers', JSON.stringify([...popovers, name]))
  }

  return (
    <PopoverContainer>
      {!isMobile && isVisible &&
        <Container color={color}>
          <CrossIcon onClick={handleClick} />
          {header &&
            <Header>
              {header}
            </Header>}
          <Content>
            {content}
          </Content>
        </Container>
      }
      {children}
    </PopoverContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good opportunity to use the queue.

I'll sketch here some of my thoughts:

1. Create array (it's our queue) in the state of parent component. This queue will contain labels or ids of popovers.
2. Parent should export enqueue and dequeue functions.
3. Popover components get access to enqueue fn, and on mounting, they push their labels/ids to the parent's state (queue).
4. In parent you only render the popover which is indexed at position 0 in queue (matching by id or smth like that).
5. Every popover has "close" function fired on dismissal, and here you additionally fire dequeue function which removes first id/label from the parent's state.
6. Parent state is updated and now it will render the popover with id that left (or won't render any popover if the queue is empty).

Important to mention, if you want to enqeueue in the similiar way as I described, do somethning like render prop instead of conditional rendering, because your popovers needs a way to store its ids in the parent state. If they don't render, they won't have a chance to enqueue theirs ids.